# nestjs get file. Why is the content of the file different?

Tags: typescript, http, proxy, download, nestjs

I want to proxy some files with my nestjs projekt. I have an URL that downloads an woff2 file when accessing it.

```
  getProxyPublic(@Req() req: Request, @Res() res: Response) {
    return this.service.proxyPublic(req.url, res);
  }
  async proxyPublic(url: string, response: Res) {
    const proxyURL = `http://originalURL/${url}`;
    return await new Promise((res, rej) => {
      get(proxyURL, (resp) => {
        let data: any = '';
        const header = resp.headers;
        resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
          data += chunk;
        });
        resp.on('end', () => {
          response.set(header).end(data);
        });
      }).on('error', (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    });
  }
```

When accessing that file via my proxy function, I do get a file just like when accessing it via browser. The problem is that the file I get by downloading it directly and doing it via code are different. The original file when opening the url in the browser and downloading it will start with those bits:

`77 4f 46 32 00 01 00 00 00 00 39 9c 00 12 00 00 00 00 84 f0 00 00 39 36 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00`

When accessing it via code and doing `Buffer.from(data)` the data will start with:

`77 4f 46 32 00 01 00 00 00 00 39 ef bf bd 00 12 00 00 00 00 ef bf bd ef bf bd 00 00 39 36 00 01`

Both files have exactly the same size but that could be because the header states the filesize.

Any idea why I don't get the right fle content?